# This product doesn't exist. error after upgrade

Tags: magento2, product, upgrade

I have upgraded my site from magento 2.3 to 2.4.0.
After upgrade, when i try to open products in backend. I am getting error as This product doesn't exist.
How can i solve this?
https://prnt.sc/2o5w295Q1iFg

Comment: Perhaps the `var/log` files can indicate which products are being displayed as `product doesn't exists`.  Without more information I don't think anyone can help accurately.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have in the grid a product that doesn't exist. Just reindex and flush the cache and it will work.

If you want to identify which are the products, search with sql query for product with product id grid that are not existing in product entity.